# How do I customize a segue based on the vale of a variable in xCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, segue

I'm currently building an iPhone app and I want to customize a segue based on the value of a variable.

For example, if the variable value is 3, I want to go to a certain view and if the variable value is 5, I would want to go to a different view.

Also, I'm using the same view controller files for all of my views. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do.

You might have a first view controller and then push a second on top of that (it can be of the same class). In that case, make sure your view controller is wrapped in a navigation controller, create a new view controller in storyboard and make it the same class and draw a segue to it. Name the segue and call it from your first view controller. In `prepareForSegue` you can customize your second view controller based on any variables.

Or you just want to show a few views in the same view controller. In this case you do not need a navigation controller. You can make the views appear, or animate them manually to slide in or out.

Usually the first approach is better because it gives you a simple mechanism to dismiss the view controller (with the different view) again.

As for the customization it would be something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   MyViewControllerClass *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
   viewController.someProperty = self.someProperty; 
}
```

Comment: Basically, the app is a survey app. There'll be about 15 questions. After each question, based on the answer, points are accumulated in a single variable. After an answer is received on the last question, I want to go to a customized screen. For example, if the user presses answer number 1 on the last question there is the possibility of going to five different screens to explain the result of the survey based on the value of the variable accumulating the overall score. So, on the last question, I want each answer button connected to five different screens, with five different segues.

Comment: You should have a view controller, say, "SolutionViewController" and just change the text based on the score. If it helped, please consider clicking the check mark.

Comment: Will do. Are you saying have one view, and have the text change based on the score? How would I go about that?

Comment: Simply give the solution view a text property (like above some property) and put in the text you like. In `viewDidLoad` fill some text view or label with the text.

Comment: Hmm.. I never thought of that. I'll play around with it. Thank you.